# Run exe in the directory without losing a context

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following structure output after compile:

```
C:.
|   start.bat
+---logs
\---App
    \---Release
        |   1.dll
        |   2.dll
        |   .....
        |   N.dll
        |   App.exe
        +---configs
        +---langs
        \---logs
```

Is there a way how to run the App.exe using this code from start.bat?
Now when I do in the start.bat `.\App\Releae\App.exe` I get an error that says that App.exe cannot find required dlls. It clear, because context path was changed. I also tried the following trick, but it doesn't work: `cd .\App\Releae & .\App\Releae\App.exe`.

Could somebody help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option using `Start` and setting the working directory with its `/D` option.

```bat
Start /DC:\App App
```

...or to protect spaces in file or directory names

```bat
Start "" /D"C:\My App" "My App.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you've `cd`ed into the folder, the `.\App\Release` path doesn't exist in the current path anymore. You need

```
cd .\App\Release & App.exe
```

Comment: First point is not necessary. It can be `cd App\Release & App.exe`

Comment: @i486 yes I know that. I intended to edit the post to add that point about `.\` but was too lazy